# qt moc.exe error

Tags: qt, compiler-errors

i'm using QT Creator 1.3.1 and trying to compile, but get this error...
please help me get rid of it

```
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/eyalk/My Documents/My QT Projects/XML'
mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/eyalk/My Documents/My QT Projects/XML'
'C:/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/bin\moc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/moc_mainwindow.cpp] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
Exited with code 2.
Error while building project XML
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check in `Tools->Options->Qt4` if the `QMake` Location is correct ? I guess QtCreator is looking for `moc.exe` in the same folder.

On many workstation, I had to manually configure the `QMake` (and `mingw`) location otherwise I would get the same error as you.

Comment: looks like the qmake is in correct place, but i dont have any file called moc.exe...

Comment: Maybe there was a problem during the installation. For instance, on my computer, `qmake.exe` is in the following path : `C:\Qt\2010.01\qt\bin` and this path is full of other executables : `moc.exe`, `lupdate.exe`, `lrelease.exe`, etc...

Do you see any of these ?

Comment: i have those...
but dont have moc.exe

Comment: well, I would try to reinstall QtCreator (or look for `moc.exe` somewhere else on your harddisk, maybe it was inadvertantly moved ?).

Comment: indd you are right :)
but now seems i get some other error:
c:/qt/2010.02.1/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQtGuid
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the QtGuid library is not found. Can you find files named `*QtGuid*` in your `qt\lib` directory (for me the full path is `C:\Qt\2010.01\qt\lib`. Have you tried reinstalling QtCreator ? It seems your install is broken !

Answer (score 1):

I had a same debug problem. Just set the system path correctly. Go to "Enviroment Variables from system variables select Path and by spliting with `;` add path were your qt is located :

```
C:\qt\4.7.4-vc\bin ().
```

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if the Build Settings/Build Direcory is not correct as well.