# Qt moc issue (moc.exe: command not found) while building Qwt with Qt 5 in Windows

Tags: qt, qt5, qwt, moc

Building Qwt with Qt 5 fails (with Qt 4 works) in Windows 7 64 bits. I tried via Qt Creator and via CLI but both ends in:

```
12:51:08: Running steps for project qwt...
12:51:08: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\qmake.exe" C:\qwt-6.1.2\qwt.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug"
Reading C:/qwt-6.1.2/src/src.pro
Reading C:/qwt-6.1.2/textengines/textengines.pro
Reading C:/qwt-6.1.2/doc/doc.pro
Reading C:/qwt-6.1.2/designer/designer.pro
Project MESSAGE: debug_and_release: building the Qwt designer plugin in release mode only
12:51:10: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
12:51:10: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j3
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/mingw482_32/bin/qmake.exe C:/qwt-6.1.2/src/src.pro -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ) && C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/qwt-6.1.2/src'
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug all
C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/qwt-6.1.2/src'
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/qwt-6.1.2/src'
moc qwt_dyngrid_layout.h
moc qwt_magnifier.h
moc qwt_dyngrid_layout.h
/usr/bin/sh: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\moc.exe: command not found
/usr/bin/sh: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\moc.exe: command not found
/usr/bin/sh: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\moc.exe: command not found
Makefile.Debug:455: recipe for target 'moc/moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [moc/moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp] Error 127
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/qwt-6.1.2/src'
Makefile.Release:455: recipe for target 'moc/moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [moc/moc_qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp] Error 127
mingw32-make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make[2]: *** [moc/moc_qwt_magnifier.cpp] Error 127
Makefile.Release:507: recipe for target 'moc/moc_qwt_magnifier.cpp' failed
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/qwt-6.1.2/src'
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'debug-all' failed
Makefile:52: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/qwt-6.1.2/src'
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first-ordered' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release-all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2
12:51:11: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qwt (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
12:51:11: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

I tried to remove all Qt installations from the computer and re-install only qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482_opengl-5.3.2.exe but the issue persists.

Any suggestion?

Comment: moc.exe cannot be found. Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872005/qt-moc-exe-error

Comment: Problem persists. Even building via command line I get the same result.

Comment: Did you check if moc.exe is anywhere on your hard disk?

Comment: Here, C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\moc.exe. Makes sense?

Comment: Nope.  Can't think of anything at the moment.

Comment: See the `/usr/bin/sh` in the beginning of `/usr/bin/sh: C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\moc.exe: command not found`? Is it normal?

Comment: Yeah, moc.exe is called from a shell script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101203/discussion-between-kcfnmi-and-metalmikester).

Comment: Definitely there's  a problem related to the `/usr/bin/sh`. I just installed Qt in a clean virtual machine and there everything works fine. I think the issue is related to a setup for cross compilation I've using in this machine. I'm trying to get rid of the cross compilation stuff. May you tell me where and when Qt reads this `/usr/bin/sh`?

Comment: Problem solved. Qt was reaching `sh` from another cygwin64 installation, removing it from path makes compilation of Qwt work.

Comment: That would have been my next suggestion, but I was away at a meeting. Glad things worked out!  Now I'll stop commenting because SO is getting mad at me. :)